# How to declare unlimited variables in a loop depending on user input?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am building a program in eclipse and I want to make a loop in which variables are declared depending on user input.
for eg, the first input is stored in a1, next input in a2, next one in a3, and so on until the user types anything other than a number `input.hasNextDouble()`.

I tried doing this using `while` loop, and `Scanner` class with `if/else` statements. But unable to figure it out. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be looking for a `List`.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Comment: Good question from an inquisitive mind, but perhaps if you continue through your Java learning material, you'll very soon come to the part where they teach you about [Java collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/), which includes the `List` as suggested by Jacob.

Comment: Use Array or List.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a **[HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)**:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    Map<String, Double> inputs = new HashMap<String, Double>();

    boolean isNumber = true;
    int count = 1;
    while(isNumber) {
      System.out.printf("Please enter a%d:", count);
      if(scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
        inputs.put("a" + count,  scanner.nextDouble());
        count++;
      } else {
        isNumber = false;
      } 
    }

    System.out.println("Inputs: " + inputs);

    // Auxiliary code for question in comments below
    double sum = 0.0f;
    for (double d : inputs.values()) {
      sum += d;
    }

    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);

    for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : inputs.entrySet()) {
      System.out.println("Sum - " + entry.getKey() + " = " + (sum  - entry.getValue()));
    }
  }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Please enter a1: 5.5
Please enter a2: 6
Please enter a3: 7.2
Please enter a4: x
Inputs: {a1=5.5, a2=6.0, a3=7.2}
Sum: 18.7
Sum - a1 = 13.2
Sum - a2 = 12.7
Sum - a3 = 11.5
```

Comment: Is it possible to interact with the inputs individually? I want to add these inputs, and then subtract each of them from the sum

Comment: Please see the auxiliary code I have added above to calculate the sum into a variable, and subtract each input from that sum.